# CSS Help for a jQuery 'Dropdown'

Tags: jquery, css

I've prepared a fiddle here: http://jsfiddle.net/zakbx/4/

**HTML**

```
<!-- filters -->
<ul class="blog-detail-dropdown">
<li>Select category
<ul class="sub_menu" id="sub_menu_category2">
    <li id="entertainment" class="14">Entertainment</li>
    <li id="film" class="15">Film</li>
    <li id="food" class="18">Food</li>
    <li id="mums" class="17">Mums</li>
    <li id="sport" class="16">Sport</li>
</ul>
</li>
<li>Sort by Blogger
<ul class="sub_menu" id="sub_menu_blogger2">
    <li class="2">Joe Bloggs</li>
    <li class="6">Keith Patterson</li>
    <li class="3">Martin Carlin</li>
    <li class="4">MC Hammer</li>
</ul>
</li>
<li>Sort by Milestone
<ul class="sub_menu" id="sub_menu_milestone2">
    <li class="7">Stage 1<span class="value">stage-1</span></li>
    <li class="8">Stage 2<span class="value">stage-2</span></li>
    <li class="9">Stage 3<span class="value">stage-3</span></li>
    <li class="10">Stage 4<span class="value">stage-4</span></li>
    <li class="11">Stage 5<span class="value">stage-5</span></li>                         
</ul>
</li>
</ul> <!-- end filter section -->
```

**jQuery**

```
$("ul.blog-detail-dropdown li").hover(function(){
    $(this).addClass("hover");
    $('ul:first',this).css('visibility', 'visible');
    }, function(){
        $(this).removeClass("hover");
        $('ul:first',this).css('visibility', 'hidden');
    });​
```

**CSS**

```
/* 
    Level One
*/
ul.blog-detail-dropdown  { 
    position: relative;
    list-style: none;
    height: 58px;
    margin: 15px 0 150px 40px;

    *z-index: 999;

    *margin-left: -5px;
}


ul.blog-detail-dropdown li  { 
    height: 58px;
    padding: 5px 20px 0 20px;
    border: 1px solid #dedede;
    background: url('/images/filter-dropdown.png') #ffffff no-repeat 155px 26px;
    color: #555;
    font-weight: bold;
    line-height: 50px;
    text-decoration: none;
    display: block;
    width: 140px;
    font-size: 14px;
    cursor: pointer;
    zoom: 1;
}

ul.blog-detail-dropdown li:hover { 
    position: relative;
    background: url('images/filter-dropdown-hover.png') #555555 no-repeat 155px 26px; 
    color: #ffffff;
    border: 1px solid #000000;
}
/* 
    Level Two
*/
ul.blog-detail-dropdown ul  { 
    visibility: hidden;
    position: absolute;
    top: 64px;
    left: 0px;
    z-index: 999;
}

ul.blog-detail-dropdown ul li  { 
    font-weight: normal; 
    background: #ffffff; 
    color: #555555; 
    border-bottom: 1px solid #000000; 
    float: none;
}
/* IE 6 & 7 Needs Inline Block */

ul.blog-detail-dropdown ul li:hover  { 
    background: #cccccc;
    color: #555555;
}

ul.blog-detail-dropdown ul li span.value {
    display: none;
}​
```

What I am trying to do is just space out each of the dropdown sections but can't think of a way to do it.

On top of that, when one of the child elements is hovered, a black border is applied but since there is already a border on the bottom, it ends up looking a bit ugly, if anyone can help me with those two parts then that would be great.

Comment: where is `hover` class in css?

Comment: `ul.blog-detail-dropdown li:hover { 
    position: relative;
 background: url('/wordpress/wp-content/plugins/wpbook/team21/images/filter-dropdown-hover.png') #555555 no-repeat 155px 26px; 
 color: #ffffff;
 border: 1px solid #000000;
}`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

is this what you're looking for?

http://jsfiddle.net/zakbx/27/

Comment: close, but I don't want the child `li`'s to be spaced apart but their parent `li`'s, e.g. `Select category`, `Sort by blogger` and `Sort by milestone` so that each 'box' is more spaced out. When you hover over one of these parent's child `li's` I am looking to keep the black border but somehow remove the bottom border of the one above so that it doesn't look as messy.

Comment: Thanks Billy, the parent boxes are separated by a margin of 10px now which is good but so are their child elements - I want those to remain together with no margin between them, confusing I know!

Comment: @martincarlin87 - I've updated my answer above with a link to a (hopefully) suitable fiddle.